# MySQL count rows within the same intervals to eachother

Tags: mysql, count, intervals

I have a table where one column is the date:

```
+----------+---------------------+
|       id |                date |  
+----------+---------------------+
|        5 | 2012-12-10 10:12:37 |        
+----------+---------------------+
|        4 | 2012-12-10 09:09:55 |        
+----------+---------------------+
|        3 | 2012-12-09 21:12:35 |        
+----------+---------------------+
|        2 | 2012-12-09 20:15:07 |        
+----------+---------------------+
|        1 | 2012-12-09 20:01:42 |        
+----------+---------------------+
```

What I need, is to count the rows which are for example whitin 3 hours to each other. In this example I want to join the upper row with the 2nd row, and the 3rd row with the 4th and 5th rows. So my output should be like this:

```
+----------+---------------------+---------+
|       id |                date |   count | 
+----------+---------------------+---------+
|        5 | 2012-12-10 10:12:37 |       2 |
+----------+---------------------+---------+
|        3 | 2012-12-09 21:12:35 |       3 |
+----------+---------------------+---------+
```

How could I do this?

Comment: Well, [**what have you tried**](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a self-join for this:

```
select t.id, t.date, COUNT(t2.id)
from t left outer join
     t t2
     on t.date between t2.date - interval 3 hour and t2.date + interval 3 hour
group by t.id, t.date
```

(This is untested code so it might have a syntax error.)

If you are trying to divide everything into 3-hour intervals, you can do something like:

```
select max(t.date), t.id, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             (date(date)*100 + floor(hour(date)/3)*3) as interval
      from t
     ) t
group by interval
```

Comment: As per the example in the question, it will return 5 rows instead of 2 .... Each row for each id ...

Comment: @NitinMidha . . . Your original *question* is not about filtering or grouping rows, it is about finding the counts within 3 hours.  You could have records every 2 hours, and they would all chain together.  I answered the question for fixed intervals.

Comment: In his expected output, he is combining row 4 and 5 into 5 and row 1,2 and 3 into 3.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to do this with My SQL but i am able to build a set of queries in SQL Server 2005 which will provide the intended results. Here is the working sample, its very complex and may be overly complex but that's how i was able to get the desired result:

```
WITH BaseData AS
(
    SELECT 5 AS ID, '2012-12-10 10:12:37' AS Date
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT 4 AS ID, '2012-12-10 09:09:55' AS Date
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT 3 AS ID, '2012-12-09 21:12:35' AS Date
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT 2 AS ID, '2012-12-09 20:15:07' AS Date
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT 1 AS ID, '2012-12-09 20:01:42' AS Date
),
BaseDataWithRowNum AS
(
    SELECT ID,DATE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date DESC) AS RowNum
      FROM BaseData
),
InterRelatedDates AS
(
    SELECT B1.RowNum AS RowNum1,B2.RowNum AS RowNum2 
      FROM BaseDataWithRowNum B1
     INNER JOIN BaseDataWithRowNum B2
        ON B1.Date BETWEEN B2.Date AND DATEADD(hh,3,B2.Date)
       AND B1.RowNum < B2.RowNum 
       AND B1.ID != B2.ID
),
InterRelatedDatesWithinMultipleGroups AS
(
    SELECT G1.RowNum1,G2.RowNum2
      FROM InterRelatedDates G1
      LEFT JOIN InterRelatedDates G2
        ON G1.RowNum2 = G2.RowNum2
       AND G1.RowNum1 != G2.RowNum1
 )


SELECT BN.ID,
       BN.Date, 
       CountExcludingOriginalGrouppingRecord +1 AS C
  FROM
      (
        SELECT RowNum1 AS RowNum,COUNT(1) AS CountExcludingOriginalGrouppingRecord
          FROM
              (
                -- If a row was used in only one group then it is ok. use as it is
                SELECT D1.RowNum1
                  FROM InterRelatedDatesWithinMultipleGroups AS D1
                 WHERE D1.RowNum2 IS NULL

                UNION ALL

                -- In case a row was selected in two groups, choose the one with higher date
                SELECT Min(D1.RowNum1)
                  FROM InterRelatedDatesWithinMultipleGroups AS D1
                 WHERE D1.RowNum2 IS NOT NULL
                 GROUP BY D1.RowNum2
              ) T
        GROUP BY RowNum1
      ) T2
INNER JOIN BaseDataWithRowNum BN
   ON BN.RowNum = T2.RowNum
```